# remove "./" of "\currfileabspath" when using lualatex

Tags: luatex, patching, currfile

I have a small problem with the package `currfile` and the command `\currfileabspath`. When compiling the file using `(pdf|xe)latex` I get the expected result, but if I use `lualatex` it adds `./` to the absolute path of the file.
I'm using TeXLive 2018 (updated) in Fedora 29, the working directory looks like this:

```
[pablo@fedora forum] $ pwd
/home/pablo/forum
[pablo@fedora forum] $ ls -lha
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x.  2 pablo pablo 4,0K feb 17 13:11 .
drwx------. 43 pablo pablo 4,0K feb 17 13:10 ..
-rw-rw-r--.  1 pablo pablo  187 feb 17 13:03 test.tex
```

My MWE (`test.tex`) is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
\begin{document}
\texttt{\jobname.pdf} created from file \texttt{\currfileabspath}%
\end{document}
```

I use the following line to compile it:

```
$ pdflatex -recorder test.tex
```

with which I obtain:

```
test.pdf created from file /home/pablo/forum/test.tex
```

which is correct, but if I change it to:

```
$ lualatex -recorder test.tex
```

I get

```
test.pdf created from file /home/pablo/forum/./test.tex
```

How can I solve this?
regards

Comment: It is easy to remove the `./` e.g. with a regex from expl3, but imho the best would be a feature request to the author of currfile.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In my mind I think it's a "bug", remove the `. /` is an option :) , I'll try something using `l3regex`, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the period is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\regex_replace_once:nnN{\.\/}{}\currfileabspath
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\jobname.pdf} created from file 
\currfileabspath%
\end{document}
```

But imho it would be better if currfile would do this, when lualatex is used, as the period and the slash is also in other commands.

Comment: Thank you very much ... with this temporarily get out of step. It would definitely be ideal for the package to do this on its own.

Comment: Sure, so make a bug report ...

Comment: Done, https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/currfile/issues/6/remove-of-currfileabspath-when-using

Comment: Bitbucket link broken, not surprisingly. Can someone update the link?

Comment: I found https://sourceforge.net/p/currfile/tickets/. Not sure if this current, but it's what is mentioned in CTAN. Only one closed ticket, and no open ticket. Someone should probably reopen it there. Unless it's not the right place for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily get the absolute path in LuaTeX using the FFI and a platform-dependent function.  On POSIX-based systems you can use the [`realpath()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realpath) function, on Windows you would use [`_fullpath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/506720ff.aspx) (I think).

Because it uses the FFI you have to enable `--shell-escape`.

In `tex.sprint` I use the first argument `-2` to switch to verbatim catcodes, in case the path contains any characters which are treated special by TeX, such as `{}$%#`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
```

```lua
local ffi = assert(require"ffi")

ffi.cdef[[
```

```c
char *realpath(const char *path, char *resolved_path);
```

```lua
]]
    
function realpath(path)
    local p = ffi.C.realpath(path, ffi.NULL)
    if p \string~= ffi.NULL then
        return ffi.string(p)
    end
    return nil
end
```

```
}

\def\currfileabspath{%
  \directlua{tex.sprint(-2, realpath(status.filename))}%
}

\begin{document}
\currfileabspath
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very interesting. The documentation (e,g. https://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html) suggests that this FFI is associated with LuaJIT, but I tested your code and it works. Would this work with larger amounts of C code, or just with small snippets? Also, when I compiled the code, there was no visible C compilation, so I don't understand how this worked without C compilation.

Comment: @FaheemMitha At some point in the past Facebook ported the LuaJIT FFI as a library to PUC-Rio Lua which is included in LuaTeX. A foreign-function interface (FFI) doesn't need a compilation step, because it only translates function calls on the fly. You can only put function declaration into the `ffi.cdef` block, not function definitions. I've also posted a relevant answer on SO some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805913/how-to-define-c-functions-with-luajit

Comment: This is actually in the Lua Posix library as `realpath`, and that is slightly preferable to wrapping the raw C `realpath`function directly with no error checking. For example, if there is no file match, `realpath` returns a null pointer. At the Lua level (or TeX level), this segfaults, which isn't very helpful. The `posix.realpath` function does a bit better than that, though I don't particularly like the way it's written.

Comment: @FaheemMitha True, calling C functions via FFI is always playing with fire because a segfault will crash the Lua interpreter and take the TeX engine with it. On the other hand luaposix is not bundled with LuaTeX and because LuaTeX uses KPSE instead of Lua's own path search it's a real pain to use third-party libraries with LuaTeX. The libc on the other hand is trivially available, even on Windows I believe because LuaTeX for Windows is built against mingw32.

Comment: It's not such a pain. You just need to use `luapackageloader` and add some paths `package.cpath` and `package.path`. It could be made easier. It seems that it isn't made so for security policy reasona.