# Why does \getabspath not work

Tags: miktex, windows, currfile

The file `main.tex` is in the current path (./main.tex). Its content is shown below.

Another file named `da.tex` is located in the subdirectory `ddd`(./ddd/da.tex). The content of da.tex is `da.tex under ./ddd`.

Running "main.tex" typesets `da.tex under ./ddd []||.`

My question is: why does `\getabspath` not find the file `./ddd/da.tex`?

PS: win7 + MikTex + Xelatex -recorder

**main.tex:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\begin{document}
\input{ddd/da.tex}
\getabspath{ddd/da.tex} [\theabspath]|\theabsdir|.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does work properly for me. Maybe try running again (with -recorder flag)?

Comment: Also maybe delete any unused .fls file, and ensure that after running it the fls file does get generated

Comment: I tried both, and the typeset is still the same. `INPUT ddd\da.tex
INPUT .\ddd\da.tex
INPUT ddd\da.tex`  This is part of my `.fls` file. Does that mean `\getabspath` can not work with `miktex`?

Comment: The fls looks correct. Are you using custom output directory?

Comment: Maybe you need to pass a backslash into `getabspath` function? (you do know how to pass a backslash of catcode other to the function, right?)

Comment: I put all temp files that generated during compilation into a directory ./tmp.

Comment: Okay, then try not specifying output directory and see if it works.

Comment: `pass a backslash into getabspath function`  How to do that?

Comment: Either `\ExplSyntaxOn \exp_args:Nx \getabspath {ddd \cs_to_str:N \\ da.tex}`, or use (my) package (needs installation however) `\usepackage{precattl}` then `\precattlExec{\getabspath{\ddd\cO\\da.tex}}`

Comment: `\ExplSyntaxOn \exp_args:Nx \getabspath {ddd \cs_to_str:N \\ da.tex}` does work!! `\theabspath` typeset `.\ddd\da.tex`. Is it a bug under `Windows` sys? And why `abspath` just begin at the current path, not from the root, like /D/.../.../da.tex?

Comment: Hm, you can tell the author of the currfile about that and see if they determine it's a bug or not. (to fix this one you need to replace backslash with slash, but only on Windows. On Linux backslash is a legal character in file name)

Comment: try `\getabspath{./ddd/da.tex}`. If you get a period to much, check https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475356/2388

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I tried with `\getabspath{./ddd/da.tex}`, The typeset is the same with `\getabspath{ddd/da.tex}`.

Comment: a sorry, mixed up texlive and miktex. Try with `\getabspath{.\string\testinput\string\aa.tex}`

Comment: Is there any general method in Tex/Latex to change path format from linux to windows? I mean  a macro, any input of linux path lead to output of windows path.

Comment: Yes there is (replace any slash with backslash. Learn some expl3 (str_replace_all) or Lua (this one is not difficult). Although it's unrelated to this question...?

Comment: @user2027729 According to the above, I think the crucial point of my question is that `\getabspath` does not work well with `windows` system. The path format has to be changed from linux to windows so thant `\getabspath` is able to identify the file and give the correct result.